# Android failing to run on Cordova with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to run an Android emulator on an Ubuntu system.  I'm behind a corporate proxy, which may be causing my problem.  I'm not sure though, because the error doesn't mean much to me (I'm new to Android).  Can anyone help?

```
cordova run android


BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.588 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
    /home/david/projects/cordova-test/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=//home/david/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
Error: android: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1623)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1584)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:357)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:380)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.getAvdManager(Main.java:295)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.displayAvdList(Main.java:1185)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:321)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

I also get a similar error when attempting to run
`./android sdk` from within the Android/Sdk/tools directory:

```
david@david-Virtual-Machine:~/Android/Sdk/tools$ ./android sdk
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1623)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1584)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:357)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:380)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:259)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:127)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SwtUpdaterData.<init>(SwtUpdaterData.java:61)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:104)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:88)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:408)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:377)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

Comment: This would be the problem with any basic plugin that got missed. Or any variable reference which is not able to load at the time of app start mostly any configuration files. You need to try with base sample app and add your modifications on top to figure out which is causing problem

Comment: @Stallion  I don't think this is a problem with any particular app.  I get the same error type when I try to run `./android sdk` from withing the tools directory.  Please see my edit.